# Error Message: Call to a member function render() on null

Tags: php, slim

actually I am trying to call my twig file from my controller and here is my code :
 **This is my App.php**

```
<?php

use Slim\App;
use Slim\Http\Environment;
use Slim\Http\Uri;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Slim\Views\TwigExtension;

$app = new App (['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' => true,],]);
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $view = new Twig('../Resources/Views/Users', ['cache' => false]); // Instantiate and add Slim specific extension$router = $container->get('router');$uri = Uri::createFromEnvironment(new Environment($_SERVER));$view->addExtension(new TwigExtension($router, $uri));return $view;};require __DIR__ . '/../Routes/routes.php';
};
```

**This is routes.php:-**

```
<?php
$app->group('/profile', function () {
    $this->get('/fetchMyLiveAds', Application\Controllers\COlxMyAdsController::class . ':fetchMyLiveAdIdsByUserId');
    $this->get('/fetchMyDeniedAds/{id}', Application\Controllers\COlxMyAdsController::class . ':fetchMyDeniedAdIdsByUserId');
    $this->get('/fetchMyPendingAds/{id}', Application\Controllers\COlxMyAdsController::class . ':fetchMyPendingAdIdsByUserId');
});
```

**This is my COlxDatabaseHandler :-**
You solved My Problem but now when i call fetchMyLiveAds() with the object of COlcUserDetails that is $this->m_objOlxUserDetails now it shows me error that call fetchMyLiveAds() on Null.

```
<?php
namespace Application\Eos;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

class COlxDatabaseHandler extends Container{

    public function __construct( ContainerInterface $c ) {

        $this->m_objOlxCategories      = new COlxCategories( $c );
        $this->m_objOlxProductImages   = new COlxProductImages( $c );
        $this->m_objOlxProducts        = new COlxProducts( $c );
        $this->m_objOlxProductStatuses = new COlxProductStatuses( $c );
        $this->m_objOlxStatuses        = new COlxStatuses( $c );
        $this->m_objOlxUserInterests   = new COlxUserInterests( $c );
        $this->m_objOlxUserLikes       = new COlxUserLikes( $c );
        $this->m_objOlxUserPurchases   = new COlxUserPurchases( $c );
        $this->m_objOlxUserDetails     = new COlxUserDetails( $c );
    }
}
?>
```

this is COlxMyAdsController class:

```
COlxMyAdsController extends COlxDatabaseHandler {
    public
    function fetchMyLiveAdIdsByUserId(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        $args = $request->getParams();
        $args = $args['id'];
        $result = count($this->m_objOlxUserDetails->fetchMyLiveAdIdsByUserId($args));
        // Here the result stores int(3)
           return $view->render($response,'profile.twig',['counts'=> $result]);
           or return $this->view->render($response,'profile.twig',['counts'=> $result]);
    }
}
```

**this is profile.twig :**

```
<div class="CSlider" ><div class="CProducts" ><table ><tr >{
    %
    for count in 1. . counts %}<td >{
    %
    block tile %}{
    %
    include 'tile.twig' %}{
    %
    endblock %}</td >{
    %
    if count is divisible by(6) %}</tr ><tr >{
    % endif %
}{
    % endfor %
}</table ></div ></div >
```

**And this is div where i want use that result**

Comment: You are using `$view` to render, but this isn't set anywhere in the local function.

Comment: @NigelRen it is not required to set it in local function beacause it is returns from container            I also Added a new line there pls check

Comment: When you create the Twig instance for the container, you never return it. It seems like there's a lot of code in the closure that's commented out. So when you try to get the `view` instance from the container, it won't actually return anything.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes here when i var_dump($this->view) or ($view) it return null

Comment: Now how can i solve it

Comment: _"it is not required to set it in local function beacause it is returns from container"_ - Just because it's in the container doesn't mean it's globally accessible. You still need to pass that instance to the method somehow. Either through the controllers constructor or to the method itself.

Comment: But also as I've already pointed out, when you add twig to the container, you must _return_ the instance in the closure: `$container['view'] = function ($container) { ...; return $view; }` - The `...` is your current code. I would suggest that you read the manual about container in Slim: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/concepts/di.html. As you can see, every example ends with a `return` statement.

Comment: even my container returns instance of view. but how can i use this in my controller

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried your suggestion but still it shows null

Comment: Well, I have no idea what you've done so I can't really comment on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to `return` the created object from your definition closure:

```php
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    // create Twig instance and set up appropriately
    $view = new Twig(...);
    // add extensions, etc...
    // You MUST return the created instance
    return $view;
};
```

When creating a controller instance, Slim passes the container instance to controller constructor as the first argument, so in controller constructor you can get the `view` from the container and save it in a private or protected variable, and later use it in your route callback:

```php
COlxMyAdsController extends COlxDatabaseHandler {

    protected $view;

    public function __construct($container) {
        $this->view = $container->get('view');
    }

    public function fetchMyLiveAdIdsByUserId(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        // logic goes here
        // ...
        return $this->view->render($response,'profile.twig',['counts'=> $result]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes you solve my Issue but now another problem is:-        when i call fetchMyLiveAds() with the object of COlcUserDetails that is $this->m_objOlxUserDetails now it shows me error that call fetchMyLiveAds() on Null.        in COlxMyAdsController.php  on the line *$result = count($this->m_objOlxUserDetails->fetchMyLiveAdIdsByUserId($args));*                 can you please check one more time

Comment: This is another issue. Please post a new question and ask this with details.

Comment: I found Solution for that Thankyou